# how spcify broser version in zalenium 's docker-compose.yml

Tags: zalenium

Is there some way to name the broser version to use in my test ?
for example , i'd like to use chrom 78 in zalenium test.
I've check the question. Some body said : it control by elgalu/selenium. but there is no way to specify the selenium version in docker run or docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the desired `elgalu/selenium` image through the `--seleniumImageName` parameter. To find out which `elgalu/selenium` image you need for Chrome 78, you can head to https://github.com/elgalu/docker-selenium/releases, and check which tag has the version of Chrome you need, when you find it, use that docker image in Zalenium through the parameter mentioned above.